# insufficient access rights on cross-reference id while deploying package

Tags: deployment, ant, package, workbench

I am getting below error while deploying package.

> Insufficient access rights on cross-reference id.

I can't even see line number.so I am not able to find issue. Please suggest

Comment: Extremely difficult to comment on this issue from the error you just mentioned, can you please add more detail to your question by adding package details, etc.

Comment: Please check access rights for all the objects which you're deploying.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue today. The root cause was that I was having delegated admin creds which I was using for deployment. This cred doesn't provide me the capability to deploy some components like I don't have permission to create a new object.
To resolve this, I just used admin creds for deployment.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/182580)

Comment: I faced the same issue. I resolved it by using admin credentials instead of delegated admin one. So, IMO it is an answer.

Comment: _Insufficient access rights on cross-reference id_ has many possible root causes. If this indeed the accepted answer, we'll delete our comment.